# Count rows in table where and then get the id and print them from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can i using Codeigniter or SQL to count the number of rows where they have the same value (Table: responds, Row: task_id), then use the task_id to print out the results from the table that contains the information (Table: tasks).

I hope you understand.

Comment: join and group_by,but can't get them to work.

Comment: Maybe you can use sqlfiddle.com and post one of them to work from.

Comment: Do you want count or row, and if it's row, base on what order and selection, given row isn't a column in the table? Bearing in mind row 1 in ascending task date order is row(n) in descending order...

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, if you're trying to get the count of taskids in the responds table and link that to the tasks table, have you tried something like this:

```
select t.taskid, t.taskname, r.taskcount
from tasks t
join 
(
  select taskid, count(taskid) taskcount
  from responds
  group by taskid
) r 
  on t.taskid = r.taskid
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/067c6/1).